# angularjs multiple dropbox selection data loading

Tags: angularjs, reload, dropdown

Hi I have three dropboxes Project service & flow 
Project  1 to Many relationship Service
Service  1 to amny relation flow
Selection of service should be by selection of project 
And selection of flowname should be on availabe service
I want to load data after selection of three dropboxes
Below is the code 
html code

```
<fieldset ng-controller="tableController">
            <select
                ng-model="selectedProject"              
                ng-options="p.projectName for p in data | unique:'projectName'" >
            </select>

            <select
                    ng-options="p.serviceName for p in data | unique:'serviceName'"                                 
                    ng-model="selectedService">
            </select>
            <select
                    ng-options="p.flowName for p in data | unique:'flowName'"
                    ng-model="selectedFlow">
            </select>                   
        </fieldset>
```

Filter not working

Json used
{id":"12345",
"name":"Log",
"projectName":"project1",
"serviceName":"service1.process",
"flowName":"flow1.process",
"aliasFlowName":"alias1","version":"1"}

Comment: Also tried tr ng-repeat="detail in data  | filter:{projectName: selectedProject, serviceName:selectedService , flowName:selectedFlow }

Answer (score 0):

Have you added unique.js reference in your app.

https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js

Comment: No I have not added

Comment: Is that fixed after adding those?